# unit testing a FlatFileItemWriter outside of Spring - "Writer must be open before it can be written to" exception

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am writing a simple batch that writes a CSV file, and I wanted to use Spring Batch `FlatFileItemWriter` for that, using Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE.

I want to unit test my writer so that I can confirm it's configured properly.

the code is very simple :

```java
    public class CSVResultWriter implements ItemWriter<Project> {

    private final FlatFileItemWriter writer;

    public CSVResultWriter(String outputResource) {

      writer=new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Project>()
          .name("itemWriter")
          .resource(new FileSystemResource(outputResource))
          .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
          .append(true)
          .build();

    }

   @Override
   public void write(List<? extends Project> items) throws Exception {
     writer.write(items);
   }
}
```

and I am writing a simple unit test without Spring, something like  :

```java
    File generatedCsvFile = new File(workingDir.toString() + File.separator + "outputData.csv");

    CSVResultWriter writer = new CSVResultWriter(generatedCsvFile.getAbsolutePath());

    Project sampleProject = Project.builder().name("sampleProject1").build();

    writer.write(List.of(sampleProject));

    assertThat(generatedCsvFile).exists();
```

But the test fails saying :

`org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to`

Looking at Spring source code, I don't understand how it's possible to make it work.. When trying to write items, the first thing that Spring does is checking that the writer is initialized :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/744d1834fe313204f06c0bcd0eedd472ab4af6be/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractFileItemWriter.java#L237

```java
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        if (!getOutputState().isInitialized()) {
            throw new WriterNotOpenException("Writer must be open before it can be written to");
        }
...
```

but the way OutputState is built doesn't give a chance to say it has been initiated :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/744d1834fe313204f06c0bcd0eedd472ab4af6be/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractFileItemWriter.java#L363

```java
    // Returns object representing state.
    protected OutputState getOutputState() {
        if (state == null) {
            File file;
            try {
                file = resource.getFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new ItemStreamException("Could not convert resource to file: [" + resource + "]", e);
            }
            Assert.state(!file.exists() || file.canWrite(), "Resource is not writable: [" + resource + "]");
            state = new OutputState();
            state.setDeleteIfExists(shouldDeleteIfExists);
            state.setAppendAllowed(append);
            state.setEncoding(encoding);
        }
        return state;
    }
```

--> the `initialized` flag in `OutputState` keeps its default value, which is false.

So I am a bit puzzled.. I guess when this is managed by Spring, some magic happens and it works.

Am I missing something obvious, or can't we really test this outside of Spring ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FlatFileItemWriter` implements the [`ItemStream`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html) contract, which will be automatically honored when used in a Spring Batch job.

If you want to use the writer outside of Spring, you need to call theses methods (open/update/close) manually. This is mentioned in the [Item Stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemStream) section of the reference docs:

```
Clients of an ItemReader that also implement ItemStream should call open before any calls
to read, in order to open any resources such as files or to obtain connections.
A similar restriction applies to an ItemWriter that implements ItemStream
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had seen the open method, but since there was an expected parameter to it that I didn't know how to provide, I didn't look in details. But it's actually quite easy : I have a test specific implementation :  public class TestCSVResultWriter extends CSVResultWriter {

  public TestCSVResultWriter(String outputResource) {
    super(outputResource);
    writer.open(mock(ExecutionContext.class));
  }

}